# How to export dataframe to json in specific format

Tags: r, json, shiny, format, export

I want to use a downloadButton in a Shiny App to download a data frame and export it to a json file. With the following code it works very well in a browser:

```
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)

ui <- basicPage(
  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Data")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(name = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria"),
                     age = c(23, 41, 32))
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "data.json"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write_json(data(), file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, the content of the json file has the following format:

```
[{"name":"Jon","age":23},{"name":"Bill","age":41},{"name":"Maria","age":32}]
```

How do I get the following format?

```
{"name": ["Jon", "Bill", "Maria"], "age": [23, 41, 32]}
```

I read the documentation of [write_json](https://rdrr.io/github/skgrange/threadr/man/write_json.html), but apparently the possibilities are limited. So other json export functions working in Shiny context would be also helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the data.frame as a list instead:

```
write_json( as.list(data()), file )
```

A simple demo:

```r
df <- data.frame(
    name = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria"),
    age = c(23, 41, 32)
)
toJSON( as.list( df ) )
```

Produces:

```json
{"name":["Jon","Bill","Maria"],"age":[23,41,32]}
```

For the record, (and perhaps konwn to you already), data.frames are lists in shape and form, only with row.names and a class:

```
> dput( df )
structure(list(name = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria"), age = c(23, 
41, 32)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

> dput( as.list(df) )
list(name = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria"), age = c(23, 41, 32))
```